# What are disadvantages of using SD card SPI mode besides reduced data rate?

Tags: spi, sd, specifications

The "SD Specifications Part 1 Physical Layer Simplified Specification Version 2.00" states on page 93:

> The  SPI  standard  defines  the  physical  link  only,  and  not  the
>   complete  data  transfer  protocol.  The  SD   Memory  Card  SPI 
>   implementation  uses  a  subset  of  the  SD  Memory  Card  protocol 
>   and  command  set.

What does it mean by "physical link only"?

When it says that SPI will only support part of the SD memory card protocol, what part is it that is not supported?

Comment: `physical link` refers to the actual wiring and associated components such as pull-up resistors and connectors and to the voltages used to transfer data

Comment: @jsotola I believe physical link also includes signalling levels and timings, i.e. "how" you pass the data. The protocol begins at "what" that data means.

Comment: Physical Layer is lowest of 7 OSI "Layers" in an application. "Please Do Not Throw Sushi and Pizza Away." https://geekstarts.info/osi-model-simplified/

Comment: The second question asks what it means by SPI only supporting part of the memory card protocol. What is missing?

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt from your link: "(OSI) is a conceptual model which was introduced to standardized the way data is transferred and received _on the network_". This model has very little to do with short-distance interfaces. Also... it feels like we discussing off-topic stuff because we don't know the answer :)

Comment: @quantum231 CD card supports multiple protocols, including 4-bit parallel. Those protocols have some specialized commands (like CRC check) that are not necessary/useful for serial communication. That is why only some of them used over SPI. Sorry, I don't know much about SD to give you more details.

Comment: Some SD cards don't fully support SPI mode, or claim to support it but don't do a very good job.

Answer (score 0):

> When it says that SPI will only support part of the SD memory card protocol, what part is it that is not supported?

In  "SD Specifications Part 1 Physical Layer Simplified Specification Version 2.00", look at table 7.3 starting on page 102, it shows clearly in the second column whether SPI mode is supported or not for the particular command.